# Minimum number of weights you need to define any integer weight from 1 to N

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, weighing

Following this question [What's the fewest weights you need to balance any weight from 1 to 40 pounds?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/186/whats-the-fewest-weights-you-need-to-balance-any-weight-from-1-to-40-pounds)

I am interested what is the minimum number M of weights you need to **define** any integer weight from a) 1 to 40? b) 1 to N?

For example, if N = 2, M = 1. Indeed, with one weight equal 2 you can define any weight X from 1 to 2 ( $1 \le X < 2 \implies X = 1$; $X = 2 \implies X = 2$ ).

With two weights I can go up to N = 8. Take weights 2 and 6, then:
$1 \le X < 2 \implies X = 1$;
 $X = 2 \implies X = 2$;
$2 < X < 6-2 \implies X = 3$;
 $X = 6-2 \implies X = 4$;
 $6-2 < X < 6 \implies X = 5$;
 $X = 6 \implies X = 6$;
 $6 < X < 6+2 \implies X = 7$;
 $ X = 6+2 \implies X = 8$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can weigh all the even numbers, you can define all the odd numbers.  The question you linked to has the weights as powers of $3:  3^0=1, 3^1=3, 3^2=9, 3^3=27$ and can weigh all numbers up to $40$.  So doubling the weights (as you started) $2,6,18,54$ allows you to define all weights up to $81$.  More generally, the series of weights $2\cdot 3^i$, for $i=0,1,2,\dots n$ lets you define all weights up to $3^{n+1}$

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the definition thing.